# Whats wrong in my reasoning in this Combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**
There are total 10 books. 4 Books on biographies, rest of the books are novels. Each student required to read a selection of 4 books, including 2 or more biographies. How many selection of 4 books satisfy the requirements.

**My reasoning:**

There are 4 required books and at least 2 of them has to be biographies. So to satisfy this, for the first two slots I select,

> $_4C_2$ ,that is 2 out of 4 biographies.

Then there remains, 2 biographies and 6 novels to choose from, that is a total of 8 books.
As these can be either biographies of novels, so it doesn't matter what type these two books are. The main constraint of 2 biographies has been fulfilled.

> So, the final two slots can be filled with books in  $_8C_2$ ways.
>
> Therefore total number of ways is - $_4C_2 * _8C_2$ ways, or
>
> 168.

**Answer:**

The above answer is clearly wrong, and the procedure to takle this problem seems to be to consider 3 cases, where

> Case1: Consider all 4 books biographies.
>
> Case2: 3 of the books biographies.
>
> Case3: 2 of the books are biographies.

And adding the ways.

Well, I understand that this is a valid way, and In fact I wanted to go this route while solving the question, I don't quite understand where my reasoning is faulty in the first approach and how it differentiates from the 2nd approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is faulty because you are overcounting. For instance, one student might choose biographies $A, B$ and $C$, and novel $X$. This should count for only one way of doing things, but you have counted it as three:

1. Choosing first $A$ and $B$ as the biographies, and then $C$ and $X$ as the free books
2. Choosing first $A$ and $C$ as the biographies, and then $B$ and $X$ as the free books
3. Choosing first $B$ and $C$ as the biographies, and then $A$ and $X$ as the free books

Note that you cannot just take your answer and divide by $3$ either, since different cases are overcounted a different number of times. The different ways of choosing two biographies and two novels are just counted once each, the different ways of choosing three biographies and one novel are counted three times each, and the number of ways to choose four biographies are counted six times each.